# matlab: detecting modifier + letter in KeyPressFcn callback function

Tags: matlab

If a callback function is assigned to the `KeyPressFcn` property of a figure, the pressed keys are available in the event data (`matlab.ui.eventdata.KeyData`) struct in the `Character`, `Modifier`, and `Key` fields.

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will return a `KeyData` struct with the following properties:

```
    Character: 'C'
    Modifier: {'shift'}
    Key: 'c'
```

For <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, however, the character is inscrutable:

```
    Character: '￧'
    Modifier: {'alt'}
    Key: 'c'
```

The numerical value of the character is `[239, 191, 167]` (`unicode2native(event_data.Character,'UTF-8')`).

Similarly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> returns an unknown character

```
    Character: ''
    Modifier: {'control'}
    Key: 'c'
```

The numerical value of the character (`unicode2native`) is `3`.

Although the key is always available through the `Key` field of the `KeyData` struct, can the key somehow also be retrieved from the `Character` field by conversion of the returned value?

Answer (score 2):

I would say no, based on the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#property_d119e285729):

> Character: The character that displays as a result of pressing the
> key or keys. The character can be empty or unprintable.
>
> Key: The key
> being pressed, identified by the (lowercase) label on the key, or a
> descriptive word.

`Alt+c` and `Ctrl+c` does not print anything to the screen, so `Character` is meaningless. You should use `Key` for it.

Comment: Thanks, the clarification about character versus key is helpful.